# Javascript beat detection using Web Audio API on mobile device

Tags: javascript, mobile, html5-audio

is there anyway to detect the beat of an mp3 or wav file using javascript's web audio api on mobile devices? I've seen it work on Desktop chrome but not on iOs

Comment: probably going to need to be working with raw bits, to low level for JavaScript in browser most likely, try Node.js platform

Answer (score 0):

Web Audio API is cross-platform solution. If it works on one browser, using standardized APIs, the solution should work with other browsers too.

1. Check preliminary browser support here for your target platforms:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=audio-api

2. Check that the actual target devices work as they advertise

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is a great platform to use across mobile devices.  Look into [Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/) for easy integration to Android, IOS, and Windows 8.

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://tech.beatport.com/2014/web-audio/beat-detection-using-web-audio/) on how to do beat detection in js.